# How to avoid using instanceof in this homework?

Tags: java, interface, instanceof

So my professor gave me a UML like this.. The other day I was talking to a friend, and he said that using  instanceOf is a bad practice..

In this example, how can avoid using it?

In the method modify, I have to use instanceOf to check if I have the instance of a professor or a student and then I made a switch to modify each attributes of the object.

Also he told me that implementing the interface in the class department make no sense. And it should be implement it in the class Person.

Any help or direction on how to improve this exercise it will be great!

```
public interface Iactions{
  void add(Object o);
  void delete(Object o);
  void modify(Object o);
  void show(Object o);
}


    public class Department implement Iactions{
    // Attributes
    ArrayList<Person> myGroupPersons;
      
    // Implementing the methods from interface Iactions
     
    @Override
    public void modify(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof Professor) {
            modifyProfessor((Professor) o);
        } else if (o instanceof Student) {
            modifyStudent((Student) o);
        }
      }
   }

public class Person {
  // code
}

public class Profesor extends Person{
  // code
}

public class Student extends Person{
  // code
}
```

Sorry for the lack of info:
Add and remove,  a method that insert an object and delete an object from the arrayList.
For show, I think is just a print of the arrayList.
And modify, I need to have like a menu, where I can select which attributes of my object I want to modify.

This is me guessing because he only give us the UML (I didn't write this uml) and he didn't say anything else.

Comment: Note that it's `implements`, not `implement`

Comment: Can you explain the method specification of add, delete, modify, and show? Add and delete are probably guessable; I assume they mean "add/remove the given object to/from this container". I'm not sure what show and modify are supposed to do though.

Comment: Were you _given_ the `Iactions` interface you posted above or did you write that yourself? It will help us help you. Based on what you said the professor asked you to do, it sounds like yes `Person` should implement that interface, and each person should do `add(department)`, `delete(department)`, `modify(person)`, and `show(null)` but really, there's a lot we don't know and even if my guess were right, it's not an easy-to-use model IMHO. :)

Comment: Using `instanceof` is no more a bad practice than using other features of Java. The point is to use the features when they make sense.  Using `instanceof` is most commonly used in overriding equals which takes an argument of type Object.

Answer (score 0):

Instanceof is not bad to use but generaly highligths bad design.

the Person class can be abstract and have a method modify.
In student and profesor you have their own implementation of the method.
this way you dont need to use

```
if (Object instanceof Student){
//code
}
```

but instead:

```
Object.modify();
```

About the interface part it works the same way.

```
public class Person implements Iactions {

public void modify(){
//code
}
}

//then call this
student.modify();
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you can use generics in java. Something like:

```
public class People {
    String name;

    public People() {
    }
}


public interface IAction<T> {
    void add(T o);
    void delete(T o);
    void modify(T o);
}


public class Departement  implements IAction<People> {

    @Override
    public void add(People o) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void delete(People o) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void modify(People o) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```